# Mysql - get multiple last result from left join

Tags: mysql, left-join

I'm sorry for my english.

I have 3 tables. contact, contact_attribut, contact_value

contact :

```
-------------------
|id     | name  |
------------------- 
|1      |  bob  |
|2      |  boby |
```

contact_attribut :

```
-------------------
|id     | code   |
------------------- 
|1      | email  |
|2      | sex    |
```

contact_value :

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|id     | contact_id | attribute_id | creation            | value
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1      | 1          | 1            | 2014-07-17 12:12:49 | bob@bob.com
|2      | 1          | 2            | 2014-07-17 12:12:56 | Male
|3      | 1          | 2            | 2014-07-17 14:15:58 | Female
```

Now I'm looking to find a query for get **all unique** attributes from one contact but the last unique attribute. Find a way for my result query looks this :

```
------------------------------------------
|name |contact_id | attribut_id | value
------------------------------------------
|Bob  |1          | 1           | bob@bob.com
|Bob  |1          | 2           | female
```

I tried this query :

```
SELECT * FROM contact AS c
LEFT JOIN contact_value as v ON c.id = v.contact_id
WHERE c.id = '1'
  AND v.creation IN 
  (SELECT MAX(v2.creation) FROM contact_value AS v2 GROUP BY v2.attribute_id)
```

But the result is :

```
------------------------------------------
|name |contact_id | attribut_id | value
------------------------------------------
|Bob  |1          | 1           | bob@bob.com
|Bob  |1          | 2           | male
|Bob  |1          | 2           | female
```

If anyone know a simple way to get the result I want?
I have simplified the tables to make it more readable.
Thanks for your time, and sorry again for this poor english.

Comment: Why do you `contact_id` of `1` set to both Female and Male? Just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do a join on a subquery which will retrieve the max creation and other values grouped by contact_id and attribute_id

something like that

```
select c.name, cv.contact_id, cv.attribute_id, cv.value
from contact c
join contact_value cv on cv.contact_id = c.id
join
    (select max(creation) as maxCreation, contact_id, attribute_id
     from contact_value
     group by contact_id, attribute_id) s
  on cv.contact_id = s.contact_id and 
     cv.attribute_id = s.attribute_id and 
     cv.creation = s.maxCreation
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82495/7)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1` in subqueries:

```
SELECT c.*,
(
  SELECT v.value
  FROM contact_value AS v
  WHERE v.contact_id = c.id
  ORDER BY v.creation
  LIMIT 1
) AS latest_value
FROM contact AS c
WHERE c.id = '1'
```